# LaTeX xwatermark package error

Tags: xwatermark

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{kotex} \usepackage{array} \usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage{xcolor} \usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage{romannum}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr} \usepackage{titlesec} \usepackage{enumitem}
 \usepackage{bold-extra} \usepackage{marginnote}
 \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{xwatermark} \usepackage{textcomp}  \usepackage{afterpage}
 \usepackage{setspace} \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage{CJKutf8}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts}
 \usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{multicol}
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{wrapfig}
 \newwatermark[allpages,color=gray!10,angle=90,xpos=90,ypos=0,scale=2]{TEXT
 FOR UNGRADUATE}

 \begin{document} page1\newpage page2\newpage \end{document}
```

For this tex file, there comes error such that

```
   Missing number, treated as zero. [...os=90,ypos=0,scale=2]{TEXT FOR UNGRADUATE}]
```

Comment: the error is due to the roman page number, `xwatermark` either doesn't expect that, or doesn't expect it the way `romannum` package sets things up.